# Why this regular expression return false?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have poor eng, Sorry for that.
i'll do my best for my situation.

i've tried to make SignUpForm using regular expression

The issue is that when i handle if statement using the regular expression

result is true at first, but after that, become false. i guess

below is my code(javascript)

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    var idCheck = /^[a-z]+[a-z0-9]{5,19}$/g; // more than 6 words
    var pwCheck = /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,}$/; // more than 8 words including at least one number
    var emCheck = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/; // valid email check

    var signupConfirm = $('#signupConfirm'),
        id = $('#id'),
        pw = $('#pw'),
        repw = $('#repw'),
        email =$('#email');

    signupConfirm.click(function () {
        if(id.val() === '' || pw.val() === '' || email.val() === ''){
            $('#signupForm').html('Fill the all blanks');
            return false;
        } else {
            if (idCheck.test(id.val()) !== true) {
                $('#signupForm').html('ID has to be more than 6 words');
                id.focus();
                return false;
            } else if (pwCheck.test(pw.val()) !== true) {
                $('#signupForm').html('The passwords has to be more than 8 words including at least one number');
                pw.focus();
                return false;
            } else if (repw !== pw) {
                $('#signupForm').html('The passwords are not the same.');
                pw.empty();
                repw.empty();
                pw.focus();
                return false;
            }
            if (emCheck.test(email.val()) !== true) {
                $('#signupForm').html('Fill a valid email');
                email.focus();
                return false;
            }
        }
    })

});
```

after id fill with 6 words in id input, focus has been moved to the password input because the condition is met. 
but after i click register button again, focus move back ID input even though ID input fill with 6 words

i've already change regular expression several times. but still like this.

are there Any tips i can solve this issue?
I hope someone could help me.

Thank you. Have a great day

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please edit your question and make it more specific and abbreviated, so it'll be easier to assist you

Comment: If you have a `form` element (not shown), your register button reloads the page, explaining why the caret would be in the first input element again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use the `global` flag on your regexes. Your code should be:

```
var idCheck = /^[a-z]+[a-z0-9]{5,19}$/;
```

When you match with the `/g` flag, your regex will save the state between calls, hence all subsequent matches will also include the previous inputs.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
var idCheck = /^[a-z]+[a-z0-9]{5,19}$/
```

removing the **g** flag
and modify the line

```
else if (repw.val() !== pw.val()) {
```